# Trivial port of SOAP ruby code to Perl SOAP::Lite fails

Tags: ruby, perl, soap

This ruby code works great:

```
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'
wsdl_url = 'http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl'
proxy = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(wsdl_url).create_rpc_driver
print proxy.NDFDgen(35.05,-106.65,"glance","2010-11-20T00:00:00","2010-11-20T07:00:00","temp")
```

This Perl code returns an empty string:

```
use SOAP::Lite; 
$client = SOAP::Lite->new(proxy => "http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl"); 
$som = $client->call("NDFDgen", 35.05,-106.65,"glance","2010-11-20T00:00:00","2010-11-20T07:00:00","temp"); 
die $som->fault->{ faultstring } if ($som->fault); 
print $som->result, "\n";
```

Pray tell why? (the Perl code is almost a direct copy/paste from "perldoc SOAP::Lite").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ruby code you reference does not work as expected -- it will return more than just the 'temp' forecast.  See http://g.chasefox.net/clearos/ruby/noaa-nws-ndfd

And regarding the perl code, I suggest reviewing NOAA's example.  They have provided examples in a few languages, one of which is perl, which utilizes SOAP::Lite.  See: http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/sample_products/ndfdXML.tar

```
print SOAP::Lite
      ->proxy('http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php')
      ->uri('http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl')
      ->NDFDgen(SOAP::Data->name("latitude" => 35.05),
                SOAP::Data->name("longitude" => -106.65),
                SOAP::Data->name("product" => "glance"),
                SOAP::Data->name("startTime" => "2011-05-08T00:00:00"),
                SOAP::Data->name("endTime" => "2011-05-09T00:00:00"),
                SOAP::Data->name("weatherParameters" => 'blah') )
       ->result
```

Comment: I think my question is: why doesn't the Perl code above work similarly to the Ruby code above, given that they're virtually identical.

Comment: because they're different languages using different libraries.  The requests must be structured correctly.  If you look at NOAA's perl example, you'll see it's a lot more involved.  I didn't just paste in a snippet because we're talking about 10s of lines to format the request correctly.

Comment: Here's a perl example similar to your ruby code.  I didn't bother with all the weather parameters because the glance product doesn't support them -- it returns 'em all.

Comment: edit: formatting lost in comment field.  So I edited my original to include the snippet.

Comment: OK, but in my Ruby example, I didn't have to specify "latitude", "product", etc. I called the NDFDgen() function using pass-by-position. Can Perl do that?

Comment: sure.  I was wondering if you might ask that after I posted my prior.  this also works (sorry for ugly formatting): print SOAP::Lite
      ->proxy('http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php')
      ->uri('http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl')
      ->NDFDgen( 35.05, -106.65, "glance", "2011-05-08T00:00:00", "2011-05-09T00:00:00", 'blah' )
      ->result

Answer (score 1):

SOAP::Lite is notoriously hard to use - you may find [XML::Compile::SOAP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aCompile%3a%3aSOAP) works better for you.